# Sublime installation on ubuntu (add-apt-repository error)

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, sublimetext2, apt-get

I am trying to install sublime onto my ubuntu server via the following method.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

But when I put the first command it gives me this error

```
sudo: add-apt-respository: command not found
```

Can anyone help me please?

Tried "Lets_eat_potatos" solution but couldnt solve the prob. this is the snapshot of the error https://www.dropbox.com/s/brsn2tpg8a2mmwj/Selection_201.png?dl=0

Comment: respository ≠ repository

Answer (score 1):

You need to install it first and then use:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `add-apt-repository` command is not found.

You need to install `python-software-properties` for it :

`sudo apt-get install python-software-properties`

Comment: This couldnt solve the problem. I am sharing the screen shot what happened when i installed this. https://www.dropbox.com/s/brsn2tpg8a2mmwj/Selection_201.png?dl=0

Comment: It looks like you're not connected to the Internet. Are maybe your system is not up to date.